# iOS - In-app purchases and beta testing

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, beta-testing

I am about to test my app with my external testers. I will give them a sandbox account to test my in-app purchases. My in-app purchases are hosted with Apple.

My question is, after the testing finishes, I disable app testing in iTunesConnect, I submit my app to Apple, and my app becomes available on the App Store. My testers download my app from App Store. Will the in-app purchases they tested still be there? Will installation from App Store act as a app update?

I tried disabling app testing in iTunesConnnect just now by making it "Not available for testing" and I'm still able to use my app, and test in-app purchases.

If I can't disable my app from testing then testers will get all my in-app purchases that they test for free?

Am I missing something? Can I disable app testing completely?

Answer (score 3):

The app in testflight will last for 30 days from the day of download. After that the app will not be available.

The live version is different and will be needed to be downloaded separately from the app store. It will be a unique application compared your beta app. It would be treated as a fresh install.

> Will the in-app purchases they tested still be there?

No

> Will installation from App Store act as a app update?

No

> will [users] get all my in-app purchases that they test for free?

No

> Can I disable app testing completely?

You already have. App will not be available for download. However you cannot remove apps that are already installed. Existing app will last until expiry date.

More info [here](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/)

Comment: So my in-app purchase will be available for 30 days even if I disable the testing before 30 days?

Comment: There will be 2 different apps testing and live. purchase in testing will be free until expire date. Live will need real purchase. When you turn off testing the app will be unavailable for download and downloaded apps will last until expire date.